# Changing The Laravel Passport/OAuth-Server Responses

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I'm building an API in Laravel 5.4, using Laravel Passport 3 for authentication. All of my API methods return a set of values that are always returned, `success`, `errors` (if there are any errors) etc.

I've changed the response of a `\Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException` throws, to fit with the rest of my app, however I'm not sure how to change the response of various token grant responses, without doing something horrible like editing the vendor files.

Comment: This question could use some context and better question, the only thing resembling it is `however I'm not sure how to change the response of various token grant responses`. Also provide some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use middleware to change your response.

From laravel documentation:

> **Before & After Middleware**
>
> Whether a middleware runs before or after a
> request depends on the middleware itself.

You can capture the response and re-format the response.

You can use laravel's `setContent` method to set the content in response. [Check here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php#L21).

Comment: I thought you might be able to do it with middleware, but didn't know how to start. This is good, thank you.

Comment: You were supposed to get the bounty, for some reason I somehow gave it to the wrong person. Not sure if there's a way to move it...

Comment: Thank you for this. And no issues for bounty. We are here to help the community. This is how we grow. And let us know the result.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do here is not supported by the library, so whatever you do will be hacky and will probably break the compatibility with future versions of `laravel/passport`.

In my opinion, you can only choose between those 2 options:

1. Instead of declaring passport routes (`Passport::routes()`) you can declare equivalent routes to your custom methods. Those method internally calls Passport classes and methods, handling passport returning values before returning them to the user. It requires a lot of digging into passport code but, at the same time, if you only add some fields (`success` or `error`) you should be able to update your code without too much effort when updating the library.
2. Fork `laravel/passport` and modify it to suit you needs. This solution in not as messy as the first, but a merge with new versions of passport in the future will probably be hard.

Of course, both are not great solutions. Keeping the standard passport responses or use a more suitable library are better options: I assume they are not feasible if you are asking.

Comment: That is a pain. Both options I'd thought of, i just hoped there was a nicer way. Currently I have my own routes which do what they need to do with handing out access tokens etc. I was hoping I could hook into something, or add some middleware to adjust the response.

Comment: @gbalduzzi is right. Modify your js function that checks if there is a success response. Check if there is `success` variable **or** `expires_in` property present in response.

Answer (score -1):

Another way - create proxy routes for your purposes.

```
Route::post('custom-auth/token', function (Request $request) {
    $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST', $request->request->input());

    $response = app()->handle($proxy);

    return responseCallback($response);
});
```

Where `responseCallback` your custom response modificator function.

Comment: I gave you the bounty by accident, but I wouldn't suggest doing this as it's quite a lot of overhead.

Comment: @DanielDewhurst, yeah. Take a note, if you will use the "middleware" solution and override the "OAuth" routes request/response formats it will cause the incompatibility with third party clients as they will expect the original "OAuth" request/response formats.